# How to override build.gradle with Jenkins job

Tags: gradle, jenkins

I need to override the `build.gradle` file with a Jenkins job.

Tried this in the build step with Jenkins gradle plugin, but didn't work:

```
-PcheckstyleTask.ignoreFailures=false
-PcheckstyleTask.checkstyleTest.enabled=true
```

**Problem:**

These values need to be updated with the the Jenkins job: `ignoreFailures`, `checkstyleTest.enabled`. What need to be done? Can someone please help me.

File `build.gradle`:

```
checkstyle {
    configFile = new File(rootDir, "checkstyle/checkstyle.xml")
    checkstyleMain.source = getTouchedFiles()
    ignoreFailures = true
    checkstyleTest.enabled = false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a project property with the `-P` flag, but this is not a property of the `checkstyle` yet. You need to use this properties as values in your configuration, something like this:

```
checkstyle {
    configFile = new File(rootDir, "checkstyle/checkstyle.xml")
    checkstyleMain.source = getTouchedFiles()
    ignoreFailures = checkstyleTask.ignoreFailures
    checkstyleTest.enabled = checkstyleTask.checkstyleTest.enabled
}
```

Though you may need to change the variable names to make them different from some build script properties and tasks. Or you may get this properies via project instance

```
//used to check, whether is property provided
project.hasProperty('checkstyleTask.ignoreFailures')

//used to get specific property value
project.properties.get('checkstyleTask.ignoreFailures')
```

Read about properies and how to use them in the [Official user guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_properties_and_system_properties)

Answer (score 0):

Stated another way, seems like you want to *configure* [Checkstyle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.Checkstyle.html) tasks based on some *condition*:

```
if (project.hasProperty("CI")) {
    tasks.withType(Checkstyle) {
        ignoreFailures = false
        checkstyleTest.enabled = true
    }
}
```

Usage: `./gradlew -PCI checkstyle`